# Sorting an array of data based on a keyvalue

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I  have an array of dictionaries with each a bunch of keys with values. I display this data in a tableview. I want to add a segmented control on top which will sort the data. One of the keyvalue's is the date in a stringformat which should sort descending, and the other is a doublevalue which should also sort descending. I thought up way too complicated solutions, like checking each value which the last and building some sort of frankstein's ladder.

I hope someone can point me in a better direction.

Comment: If you can get the date as a `NSDate` then you can just use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
NSSortDescriptor * descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"theDateKey" ascending:NO];
[searchTermsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```